# Form Validation using jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have feedback form on my mvc4 site and I'd like to make validation for my form.
I try to use [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)
I added jQuery library and `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`
Then I wrote (for one field to try)

```
     <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#feedback-form").validate();

        $("#feedback-form").validate({
            rules: {
                Name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
            },
            messages: {
                Name: {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in my form

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Feedback", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "feedback-form" }))
    {
 <!-- Name -->
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "text-field" })
             <a href="#" class="link1" id="submit-button" onclick="document.getElementById('feedback-form').submit()"><em><b>Send</b></em></a>
}
```

It doesnt show any mistakes in browser console, but validation doesnt work. When I push Send-button with empty field for example, I receive nothing, no messages.
What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have included the jquery library itself, too?

Comment: Of course! I said I added jQuery library!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$("#feedback-form").validate();` and it should work fine.

Comment: Try this way, this worked for me. `jQuery("#UserName").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter your name"`
                });

Comment: Put a seperate validation for all fields. Here UserName is a text-box id.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest you is do not try to validate when doc is ready instead you can try on submit of the form and there is no need to put two methods of validate and remove the extra `,` commas you have in your validation:

```
$(function () {
    $("#feedback-form").on('submit', function(){
      $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            }  // <-------------------------removed comma here
        },
        messages: {
            Name: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            }  // <-------------------------removed comma here
        }      // <-------------------------removed comma here
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work again :( No mistakes in console, but it doesnt work :( I cant undestand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
         form.submit();
          }
```

and Remove

```
 $("#feedback-form").validate();
```

and Remove ,

```
 Name: {

        } , <--- here you add "," for 1 more rule or message
```

Comment: Explain me, please, where should I add `submitHandler: function(form) {
         form.submit();
          }` ?

Comment: after messages  attributes  u need to add it